# How to use custom font on codepen

Tags: css3, шрифты

Здравствуйте. Я новичок в css и практикуюсь на codepen

Я хочу использовать шрифт загруженный из интернета  и закинул его на github, но почему-то шрифт все-равно не подгружается .

Ссылка на проект: [https://codepen.io/Oleg2805/pen/GqqyQZ](https://codepen.io/Oleg2805/pen/GqqyQZ/)
    или css который я использую.

```
   @font-face{
  font-family: GodOfWar;
  src: url(https://github.com/Oleg2805/Tribute/raw/master/GODOFWAR.TTF);
}
#text1{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.5em;
  font-family: 'GodOfWar';
}
```

Comment: Please, write in russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по информации из https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions `github` отдает файлы с заголовком `Content-Type: text/plain`, и браузер игнорирует такой шрифт.

Но вы можете использовать сервис `rawgit`, который исправляет это. По такому url:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/Oleg2805/Tribute/master/GODOFWAR.TTF, шрифт возвращается с  заголовком `content-type:application/x-font-ttf`. С ним шрифт отображается нормально.